# Bullets moving with the camera, not the world, Java 2D

Tags: java, 2d, mathematics

I'm building a simple 2D Top-Down shooter game in Java.

I simply cannot get this to work:
I'm moving the camera and world differently. The world is moving when needed (when not in one edge, so it gives nice effect of not showing outside of the world). When the player moves and edges are not visible, the camera is moved when the player moves.

I implemented bullets right now, but the bullets move with the camera, not the world, like the correct physics should be :D

For moving the world relative to player position and camera, I'm using X and Y offsets.

Now the problem:
I'm creating a new bullet like this in my Player.java class:

```
new Bullet(handler, angle, x + width / 2 - handler.getCamera().getxOff(), y + height / 2 - handler.getCamera().getyOff(), 2, 4);
```

Bullet constructor:

```
public Bullet(Handler handler, double rad, double x, double y, double speed, int r)
```

I have to add half the width and height of the player, because otherwise it will shoot at the corner of my player sprite. Camera X and Y offsets to the bullet X and Y, because otherwise the bullet will be drawn to the coordinates relative to the world and will not shoot from correct places. But when the bullet is moving it moves with the camera.

Really wouldn't like to change the Camera movement!

Comment: I think the problem probably lies in whatever update or tick function you have on your bullet, so if you could share that that would be great.

Comment: My bullet tick() method:

`public boolean tick() {
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  
  if(x < -r || x > handler.getWidth() + r ||
     y < -r || y > handler.getHeight() + r) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }`

Comment: If the tick method returns true, the bullet will get deleted. It's a removal if the bullet gets out of bounds.

Comment: This is my full Bullet.java class, excluding getters and setters and defining variables: http://imgur.com/dcf23se

Comment: Well why are you talking about the camera when you construct bullets? Right now you're constructing the bullet at a different place depending on where teh camera is. Obviously that's a problem.

Comment: I'm moving the world and camera separately, so I have to add the camera's X and Y offsets, otherwise the bullet doesn't spawn to correct place.

Comment: Basically, when spawning the bullet with the player's x and y, it spawns on those coordinates relative to the screen, when adding camera X and Y offsets it spawns in the correct place but doesn't move right :/
How could I spawn it relative to the world, not the screen?

Comment: Well why does it "spawn on those coordinates relative to the screen" when you spawn it with the player's X and Y? Do players and enemies and walls also "spawn on coordinates relative to the screen"?

Comment: Good point dude, no wonder why my entities weren't spawning to correct places when adding multiple of. Now got it fixed - the entities and bullets!

Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, the world never moves. The camera does, so you should just make the camera move, instead of both the camera and the world (that just doesn't make sense to me).